# Writing a subset of $\mathbb{M}(2,2)$ as a plane in $\mathbb{M}(2,2)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, plane-geometry

Working on the book: Robert Messer. "*Linear algebra - The gateway to mathematics*" (p. 63)

> 18. Write the set $\left\{
>     a
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>       2a-b & b+5\\
>       a+2 & a+b
>     \end{bmatrix}
>     \in \mathbb{M}(2,2)
>     \Bigm| a,b\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$ as a plane in $\mathbb{M}(2,2)$.

The solution is:

$$\left\{
a
\begin{bmatrix}
  2 & 0\\
  1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}+
b
\begin{bmatrix}
  -1 & 1\\
  0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 5\\
  2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\Bigm| a,b\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

- Does this representation has the form $\left\{
  r\mathbf{v}+s\mathbf{w}+\mathbf{x} : r,s \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$ ? If so, do $\mathbf{v}$, $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ consist of two pairs of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
- Which are the direction vectors in this set ?

I cannot see how the solution set represents a plane and which are the vectors (I see three matrices there).

Answer (score 1):

Use the basis $e_1=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, $e_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, $e_3=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, $e_4=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Do you recognize your matrices as vectors now?

Comment: Thank you, @mathma ! Unfortunately, I do not recognise them. I fell I am missing something obvious. Could you give me more detail ?

Comment: You can write each of your matrices as a linear combination of the $e_i$ matrices, the coefficient of $e_i$, will be the $i$-th coordinate.

Comment: Thank you, @mathma. So, the plane can be written as the set $$\{a(2,0,1,1)+b(-1,1,0,1)+(0,5,2,0)\mid a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ Is this correct ? I am still not sure how to does the conversion between 2 by 2 matrices and vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ work.

Comment: @F.Zer yes you did the conversion correctly. it does not matter if they are matrices, tuples, polynomials, etc. as long as they satisfy the axioms of a vector space.